# Rails: Chained database query from multiple classes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope

I have an app that is intended to sort all user articles by identical user fields. An example of this is if a user wanted to see all other user articles from users with a similar occupation. Each user has an occupation (string) field in the database. I've been able to filter all users with identical occupations by using this query:

`similar_users = User.where(occupation: current_user.occupation)`

I have been unsuccessful at filtering their articles by `similar_users`. Articles have an `author_id` which is equal to the `user.id`.

I've tried chains such as `Articles.similar_users`, `Articles.similar_users.where(author_id: user.id)`, or `Article.all.where(author_id: similar_users.id)`, but they don't work and rightly so. How would I go about chaining these classes? Is there more effective way, such as using named scopes with lambdas?

In Article.rb

```
  belongs_to(
  :user,
  class_name: "User",
  foreign_key: :author_id,
  primary_key: :id
  )
```

In User.rb

```
has_many(
:articles,
class_name: "Article",
dependent: :destroy
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to something like

```
Article.includes(:user).where("users.occupation = ?", current_user.occupation)
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about SQL injections?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I avoided them because I've heard they pose security threats if someone was able to inject their own code.

Comment: @VictorMoroz let me know how could you possibly break the above generated sql. I haven't consider anything like data is coming from user-input or so. I would update the answer or delete it. thanks

Comment: I tried that code on another repository that functions identically, but with `Post` instead of `Article` and I got this error `#<#<Class:#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Post:0x0000010475d0a0>>:0x823ae850> `

Comment: Rule of thumb is to assume that string fields can always come from user input. Use placeholders (? or :name), they were created for a reason.

Comment: @VictorMoroz thanks for valuable input,  how i skipped it...i dont know. Updating.

Comment: @user3181113 , may be you missed replacing `articles`. i have updated the post, give a try.

Comment: Getting this error: `SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting '='`

Comment: Nope, fixed that error, but still receiving `=> #<#<Class:#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Post:0x000001046971c0>>:0x8234b8e0>`

Comment: Even ran this: `Post.includes(:users).where("users.occupation = '?' , posts.author_id = '?' ", current_user.occupation,current_user.id).references(:user)`. This repository has absolutely no mentions of Article, it was build from the ground up to use Post.

Comment: please update the question and specific the relationship between user and post. Does it hosts any "has_many"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48741/discussion-between-paritosh-piplewar-and-user3181113)